# cant allocate free space to partition ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I have 26GB of unlocatted space and I want to add that space to my existing partitions. The problem is that i cant seem to use use that space to resize the partitions.

Here is my partitions list in gparted [image]

I want to copy the free space to the /dev/sd6 partition but the option resize is greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resize option is likely grayed out since the partition is mounted. Since it appears this is your root partition, your best option is probably to use a [GParted LiveCD or LiveUSB](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). Once you boot from that drive, you should be able to resize/move any partition on the drive.

Comment: thanks. i have created a gparted live cd and it does the trick.